# py4j from pyspark - launch_gateway() error

Tags: python, py4j

Step1 - I have created a jar out of sample java code- **MyPythonGateway.jar**

Java Class-

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;
public class MyPythonGateway{

    public int findMyNum(String input){
        return(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GatewayServer server = new Gatewayserver(new MyPythonGateway())
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Step2- I am invoking pyspark by mentioning this jar- **MyPythonGateway.jar** in executor.extraClassPath and driver.extraClassPath

pyspark is launched well.

Step3- trying to invoke java code from pyspark now

> Error: Py4jNetworkError: An Error occurred while trying to connect to
>   the Java server (127.0.0.1:25335)

**I used other ports also like- 25340 , 25338 but getting same error every time**

Comment: also tried using next available port-                                                                       'from py4j.java_gateway import (
    JavaGateway, CallbackServerParameters, GatewayParameters,
    launch_gateway)

port = launch_gateway() '                                                                                                                   .                                                                                                                            *getting error-Py4jError:could not find py4j jar at*

Comment: also tried using next available port-                                                                       `from py4j.java_gateway import (
    JavaGateway, CallbackServerParameters, GatewayParameters,
    launch_gateway)

port = launch_gateway()`                                                                                                                   .                                                                                                                            **getting error-Py4jError:could not find py4j jar at**

Comment: @Barthelemy - can you please help on this